# Is there a way to lock user inside an app so the main screen can not be accessed unless password entered

Tags: flutter, locking

I am working on an app where the user will be able to hand their phone to someone to complete a survey. When they hand the phone over I would like to lock the other functions of the phone so the person they hand it to can not go to the main screen or access anything other than the app survey questions.

So far I have tried looking into systemchrome class but have not had any luck. Closest I got is...
`SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);`  This only hides the native nav bars but does not stop access of the main screen.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you seek is further than an application feature. It's more like a OS policy. On android you can use **Android Enterprise** and **kiosk** apps to full-fill your requirement. This link will guide you through the process.

https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/6396012?hl=en